# Android: MediaMetadataRetriever caused "java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000"

Tags: android, video, android-intent, runtimeexception, mediametadataretriever

I am trying to pick video file through intent and extract meta data from the video.

However, I got some error reports from users and reporting following exception:

```
Exception java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=12004, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://media/external/images/media/63141 flg=0x1 (has extras) }} to activity {my.app/my.app.VideoActivity}: 
java.lang.RuntimeException: setDataSource failed: status = 0x80000000
```

Here is the code grabbing meta data:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);
    Uri uri = intent.getData();
    MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
    try {
        retriever.setDataSource(this, uri); // error occurs here
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();           
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();           
    }
}
```

Why does the exception appears and how to fix it?

Comment: have you made any progress on this? Investigating the same issue with no success yet and it only occurs on KK devices in my tests

Comment: would like to know how you solved this problem! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One issue with this method in more recent API versions is that it requires manifest permissions and this is not always obvious form the error message - see this discussion: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=35794

If this is the issue then for your case I think your URI looks like it is to a local file so you would want file read/write permission. If it was an internet URL then you would want internet permission.